# Meteor: Collection created but returned empty

Tags: meteor

I have this simple code, basically trying to recreate Players example from scratch. I created a project with a line

```
meteor create simpl
```

and have this code

```
Players = new Meteor.Collection("players");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    console.log(Players.find().count());
  });


if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (Players.find().count() === 0) {
      Players.insert({name:"meteor"});
      Players.insert({name:"meteor1"});
    }
  });
}
```

The console outputs 0. The equal code for insertions and retrieval in the *Leaderboard* example works as expected but not this one. Am I doing something wrong in the code or creation of the project?

**UPDATE:**

After reading some comments and answers about requirement to Publish on the server and Subscribe on the client, I would like to ask how come it is possible that the *Leaderboard* example has no such code, yet works as I'd expect.

Comment: Looking at the documentation (http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp), it appears after creating the collections you need to publish them on the server and subscribe to then on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor is built using a data on-the-wire principle. So when the javascript is loaded your collections still need to be downloaded from the server.

*If you wait a small amount of time* then run `console.log(Players.find().count());` it should work as you want. Using the following would work (as `Deps.autorun`) will be rerun when the `Players` collection changes:

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
    console.log(Players.find().count());
});
```

Initially it will print `0`, but when the data is downloaded it will increase.

Another option is to use the subscription callback to determine when all the data has been downloaded from the server.

Comment: There is no such code in leaderboard example, yet it behaves exactly as I described, it retrieves the collection correctly in client startup function. How is that possible?

Comment: If you wait a bit and run `console.log(Players.find().count());` in your javascript console does it work?. The leaderboard example has a startup function on the server side but not on the client.

Comment: There isn't any code that runs on the leaderboard example on the client side at startup afaik. Could you show the code you're using?

Comment: I added startup code myself into leaderboard just to check if it works. If I log the collection later as you said then I do get the correct count. I'd like it to make it work as in Leaderboard though, if possible. Or at least know why is it behaving differently.

Comment: It would work if the collection data is downloaded before the startup function is run. If latency is very low, the project is very small, and the size of the collections are small it could happen. But it should break with a larger project (trying to access collections in `Meteor.startup()`)

Comment: Is there a way then to know when everything is loaded, so I can do some initial processing and actions based on the current state of collections?

Comment: Yes you can use the subscription callback which will be called when the subscription for a particular collection is complete, See http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe

Comment: Ok, I guess this comment thread explains where my problem came from, and what to do for initial processing. Thanks.

Comment: @MuneebMirza previously `Tracker` was called `Deps`. I've updated the answer to use `Tracker`.

Comment: @Akshat if i just do like Players.find().count() it doesn't work unless i do  console.log of its returned value. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

The leaderboard example ships with Autopublish (limited documentation on it here: http://docs.meteor.com/#dataandsecurity). Autopublish essentially does a global publish-subscribe for all data for all clients. It's not secure, but it's why the Leaderboard example has no publish or subscribe features

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish the collection server side and then subscribe client side

Check meteor documentation

Comment: Again, looking at the leaderboard example, there is no "publish" code there in the source, or I'm overlooking it.